# How to avoid conflict with manager when he complains for situations beyond my remit?

Tags: relationships, politics, team-role

I am part of a small team for a big region.
Other teams, smaller or not much bigger, operate in other, smaller regions.
Together, we cover "the whole world".

I am working on projects focused on my team's regions.
When senior leadership - above my manager - heard about our project, we were asked to include other regions as well. This caused friction, as some other regions 1) have their own ideas, 2) don't want our region to try and tell them what to do, 3) don't want so support projects coming from other teams in general.
Within the region supported by my team, things are going well, people are getting involved and we are making good progress.
There has been friction and pushback from the other teams, an I spent much longer selling our project to them than to customers in general.

Now my manager is coming to me with complaints. All these complaints come from discussions with the other regions. Tensions, frictions, stalling, etc. all come from outside, in our region there are no complaints and we make great progress.
My manager is pushing our team to be ambitious and work on projects of "national scale" or "global". I am also being asked to create content, documents and other sales artifacts for the whole global organisation.
But:

1. I am still focused on my region
2. I want to stay focused on my region

If I focused on my region, I would have no discussions or frictions.
My manager keeps pushing us to do "big things".
I want to focus on what is my remit, but I don't know how to do this without damaging the relationship with my ambitious manager.

**Question: how to work within on your actual role and responsibilities, when your manager pushes you to informal, wider responsibilities?**

Comment: Just to be clear, is this *senior manager* you're talking about responsible for only your region, or does he actually have any worldwide responsibilities?

Comment: thanks, I updated the question.

Comment: Joe, come on, that was more of an attack than a comment or answer.

Comment: I wonder if whoever is ordering you to take over the world is actually aware of the situation and the other teams? Have they told the other teams to follow your orders?

Comment: Make your manager aware that "global" responsibilities require global rights. Like telling people what to do from "National" point and not regional.

Answer (score 2):

#### Talk to your boss about talking to his bosses regarding other regions’ pushback.

Simply put, your boss is giving you a goal to work on, but people on other teams outside his control are making themselves into blockers and refusing to cooperate. As your manager, his job is to remove blockers and facilitate you being able to do your job.

As a result, I would recommend talking with him about the difficulties you’ve faced implementing his global goals, and ask him to speak with his bosses about either making the other teams cooperate with yours via a mandate from on high, or abandoning your global project as unfeasible.

Answer (score 2):

You should speak with your manager about the direction you want to take your career. Focusing on the region while management wants to make the focus more global might end up with all sorts of things happening.

### The Bad?

Actively challenging the ambitions of your manager (and the company as a whole it seems) may end up with you being retained, with someone put in charge of you who mirrors the manager's desires more closely. It might also end up with you being replaced. The fact of the matter is that your manager is onboard with what their managers are wanting to do with the company.

### The Good?

Well, you might get to keep focusing on that region? Maybe? I guess one good thing is that the other regions behaved like one would expect. How you deal with that though is up to you. Leadership is looking to your team and management to mitigate the resistance of the other regions, get buy-in, and take the company in the direction they desire.

### The Ugly

Not managing this situation tactfully by assessing the battlefield correctly could be disastrous for you depending on the size of your industry, the connectedness and respect of your manager/senior management, how visible you were in the company, etc. If you were to be removed because you weren't playing ball, and were sufficiently high/visible enough in the company, you might have a hard time getting work with other major players. Even great managers can be passed up when they won't play the game their superiors want to play.